# JavaScript: How can I access the string value of a String object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extend a method to the String **prototype**.

I want this method to manipulate the string value but I am not sure how do access it.

`this` the current object context seems to refer to the string object, but not the actual string value.

```
String.prototype.test = function() { console.log(this)}
function () { console.log(this) }
'lol'.test()
 VM192:2 String {0: "l", 1: "o", 2: "l", length: 3, 
 has: function, contains: function, 
 escapeRegExp: function, camelize: function…
}
```

How do I access the string value instead of the string object?

Comment: The string object **is** the string, for all practical purposes. What you are seeing in the console is an artifact of some internal machinery combined with how `console.log` works. In all other contexts, the string object is essentially identical to its primitive value. In this case, in addition to using `toString()` as suggested in the answers, you can also say `this+""` or `this.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need call `toString()`

```
String.prototype.test = function() { 
    console.log(this.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method:

```
console.log( this.toString() )
```